# Problemas vbscript en produccion

Tags: vb6, vbscript

Buen dia,
Tengo un grave problema, Estoy revisando una pagina realizado en asp clásico y vb el cual tiene incluido VBSCRIPT, el mismo dejo de funcionar de repente y he buscado como solucionarlo y no quiere funcionar, el error que da es

> Server Error: 500 - Internal Server error

He revisado:

- Cambiando version de navegador del Edge o IE11 a IE10 sigue con el mismo error con F12
- Agregar este codigo `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">`

El codigo vbscript es la siguiente.

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
dim StrPlan
StrPlan =   "<table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""505"">"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "<tr>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "<td valign=""middle"" width=""503"">"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "&nbsp;"

StrPlan = StrPlan & "<p><font face=""Arial""><b>Planes</b></font></p>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "<table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" width=""100%"">"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "<%Call STRPlanesDeRegistroActual()%>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "</table>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "</td>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "</tr>"
StrPlan = StrPlan & "</table>"

Sub DalePlanes()
    document.all.FontMenuPlan.size = "2"
    document.all.FontMenuDep.size = "1"
    document.all.FontMenuRec.size = "1"
    document.all.FontMenuPrimas.size = "1"
    <% if session("ENTE") = 2 then %>
        document.all.FontMenuCiaSeg.size = "1"
        document.all.FontObservaciones.size = "1"
    <% end if %>
    document.all.Muestra.innerhtml = StrPlan
end sub
```

Cuál podría ser el error?

Agradecido de antemano

EDICION

Activando opciones para visualizar mas errores tanto en IIS y IE muestra el siguiente mensaje.

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'
>
> Unterminated string constant
>
> /-/-/DatosEmpLimitado.asp, line 101
>
> StrPlan = StrPlan & "<%Call STRPlanesDeRegistroActual()

Comment: hice un copy paste de tu código y lo que me arroja el editor es que le molesta el símbolo   `%` no se de vbscript así que no se si es necesario pero quizás eliminándolo se arregle tu problema

Comment: @LPZadkiel Buenos dias! pero sin ese simbolo no podre acceder al servidor o si?

Comment: como mencioné antes no se mucho de vbscript, pero creo que así no se hacen las llamadas a servidor

Answer (score 0):

El problema era el metodo STRPlanesDeRegistroActual(),

Lo comente y funciono con normalidad

Comment: Supongo que ese método no lo tenías, pero en todo caso sería bueno si sabes por que funcionó que lo compartieras